# EF Core: How to get RowNumber from database?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, memory-leaks

My program gets from client this query:

```
var productsQuery = context.Goods
    .Select((p) =>
        new {
            Name = p.Name,
            Type = p.Type,
            BestBefore = p.BestBefore,
            ShopId = p.ShopId
        })
    .Where((p) => p.Type == "Food");
```

Result of this query has more then 500 000 records. My purpose is to get the index and good object from this query according to one condition:

```
// variable selectedShopId is given earlier
var productObject = productQuery
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select((p, i) =>
        new {
            Index = i,
            Product = p
        })
    .Where(p => p.Product.ShopId == selectedShopId)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

I tried make AsEnumerable(), but it doesn't help me.

Comment: The row number before or after filtering? Is the purpose for pagination?

Comment: @gunr2171 row number must be before filtering. Yes, I need row number for pagination in future steps of developing.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` is a bad idea as you will pull across all data and then throw most of it away. I don't think row number is readily accessible in EF (what version?) but you can use `Skip`/`Take` for pagination.

Comment: @NetMage my task is to show page where element is and highlight it in the paging sample on the frontend part. Have I understood you right that your way is to loop through pagination samples and find suitable record?

Comment: Then I think you need the row number after filtering, because the number of pages depends on the number of items after filtering.